# Two lines of text at bottom of image

Tags: css

I have two pieces of text that I want put on top of an image at the bottom just like this:

[image]

However, right now it looks like this instead:

[image]

Here is the HTML:

```
 <div class="image">

 <%= image_tag @post.image %>
 <div class="toptext">
 Lorem ipsum dolor
 </div>
 <div class="bottomtext">
 Lorem ipsum
 </div>

 </div>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
 .image img {
   width: 100%;
   height: 500px;
 }

 .image {
   position: relative;
 }


 .toptext {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
   left: 0;       
   background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);       
   font-size: 40px;
  }

  .bottomtext {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;        
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
   }
```

How do I get both lines at the bottom of the image with the 'bottomtext' below 'toptext'?

Comment: The top, right, bottom, and left of 0 will stretch an absolute block over its parent.  Just use bottom and left coordinates to position your text and get rid of margins.

Comment: give width="100%' in .toptext

Comment: @DRD The thing is i'm using that to stretch the .toptext background so the text is easier to read on the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that places the image as a background of the containing element and positions the text segments absolutely within the container.  Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5Kf5n/.

HTML:

```
 <div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    padding: 10px;
}

body > div {
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    background: url(http://placehold.it/500x300px) no-repeat;
    position: relative;
}

div > p {
    font: bold 24px/1 Sans-Serif;
    color: #121212;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 50px;
    left: 70px;
}

div > p + p {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-style: italic;
    bottom: 25px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set .bottomText margin-top property it will serve your purpose. i had made it 60.

```
.bottomtext {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;        
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: 60px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
   }
```

Comment: This doesn't really solve my main problem of getting the text to sit at the bottom.